# the (find, findbyid, create) method has not been setup loopback

Tags: loopbackjs, strongloop

I'm trying to setup loopback and so far I've created a db connection to mysql, a model, and am now using the api explorer to test it but I keep getting this error on any call:

```
"The find method has not been setup loopback. The PersistedModel has not been correctly attached to a DataSource!
```

Here is the complete response:

```
{
  "error": {
    "name": "Error",
    "status": 500,
    "message": "Cannot call EaAssets.find(). The find method has not been setup. The PersistedModel has not been correctly attached to a DataSource!",
    "stack": "Error: Cannot call EaAssets.find(). The find method has not been setup. The PersistedModel has not been correctly attached to a DataSource!\n    at throwNotAttached (C:\\cmdb\\node_modules\\loopback\\lib\\persisted-model.js:62:11)\n    at Function.find (C:\\cmdb\\node_modules\\loopback\\lib\\persisted-model.js:210:5)\n    at SharedMethod.invoke (C:\\cmdb\\node_modules\\strong-remoting\\lib\\shared-method.js:252:25)\n    at HttpContext.invoke (C:\\cmdb\\node_modules\\strong-remoting\\lib\\http-context.js:384:12)\n    at phaseInvoke (C:\\cmdb\\node_modules\\strong-remoting\\lib\\remote-objects.js:645:9)\n    at runHandler (C:\\cmdb\\node_modules\\loopback-phase\\lib\\phase.js:135:5)\n    at iterate (C:\\cmdb\\node_modules\\async\\lib\\async.js:146:13)\n    at Object.async.eachSeries (C:\\cmdb\\node_modules\\async\\lib\\async.js:162:9)\n    at runHandlers (C:\\cmdb\\node_modules\\loopback-phase\\lib\\phase.js:144:13)\n    at iterate (C:\\cmdb\\node_modules\\async\\lib\\async.js:146:13)"
  }
}
```

here is my model-config.json

```
{
  "_meta": {
    "sources": [
      "loopback/common/models",
      "loopback/server/models",
      "../common/models",
      "./models"
    ],
    "mixins": [
      "loopback/common/mixins",
      "loopback/server/mixins",
      "../common/mixins",
      "./mixins"
    ]
  },
  "User": {
    "dataSource": "db"
  },
  "AccessToken": {
    "dataSource": "db",
    "public": false
  },
  "ACL": {
    "dataSource": "db",
    "public": false
  },
  "RoleMapping": {
    "dataSource": "db",
    "public": false
  },
  "Role": {
    "dataSource": "db",
    "public": false
  },
  "EaApplication": {
    "dataSource": "db",
    "public": true
  },
  "EaAssetCapabilityRelation": {
    "dataSource": "db",
    "public": true
  },
  "EaAssetTyp": {
    "dataSource": "db",
    "public": true
  },
  "EaAssetStatus": {
    "dataSource": "db",
    "public": true
  },
  "EaAssetLocation": {
    "dataSource": "db",
    "public": true
  },
  "EaAssetRelation": {
    "dataSource": "db",
    "public": true
  },
  "EaAssets": {
    "dataSource": null,
    "public": true,
    "$promise": {},
    "$resolved": true
  },
  "EaCapability": {
    "dataSource": "db",
    "public": true
  },
  "EaRelationType": {
    "dataSource": "db",
    "public": true
  },
  "EaServers": {
    "dataSource": "db",
    "public": true
  },
  "EaServices": {
    "dataSource": null,
    "public": true,
    "$promise": {},
    "$resolved": true
  },
  "EaBuildTyp": {
    "dataSource": "db",
    "public": true
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `EaAssets` model has a datasource of `null` so the built-in remote methods are not getting attached